# Detecting TextToSpeech process death

Tags: android, deadlock, text-to-speech

I'm developing an Android app which keeps the user informed about their progress by showing a message on screen and simultaneously reading it with `TextToSpeech`. In order to keep the visual and audible stimuli synchronised, I listen for the `Done` event. However, I'm finding that after a moderate amount of time (typically somewhere between 20 and 40 minutes), memory pressure causes Android to start killing processes, and eventually it kills the speech service. In logcat I'm seeing lines like

```
I/ActivityManager(  565): Process com.google.android.tts (pid 7546) has died
```

Sometimes I can detect this because when I call `Speak` it returns `OperationResult.Error`. However, occasionally it gets far enough to raise the `Start` event but then dies, and never raises anything else. logcat shows

```
I/TTS     (11462): @636468802271461960: Speak(...) returned Success
I/TTS     (11462): @636468802271474010: Start utterance88
I/TextToSpeech(11462): Asked to disconnect from ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
I/TextToSpeech(11462): Connected to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
I/TextToSpeech(11462): Set up connection to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
```

(where the first two lines are from my listener, below).

Looking through the [public source code for `TextToSpeech`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.java) I see that it detects the death of the process via a binder and reconnects, but I can't see any hook to be notified, and I can't see how to get access to the binder myself (except by using reflection to hack access to private fields, which is not exactly a good practice).

Is there any way to be notified when the wrapped speech service resets, or do I have to just add generous timeouts?

---

#### My listener

(Code is in C# because I'm using Xamarin for Android, but if you can read Java that shouldn't be much of a problem).

```csharp
public class TTSProgressListener : UtteranceProgressListener, IDisposable
{
    protected internal TTSProgressListener(TextToSpeechWrapper wrapper)
    {
        _TTS = wrapper ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(wrapper));
    }

    private readonly TextToSpeechWrapper _TTS;

    #region UtteranceProgressListener

    public override void OnStart(string utteranceId)
    {
        Android.Util.Log.Info("TTS", $"@{DateTime.Now.Ticks}: Start {utteranceId}");
    }

    public override void OnDone(string utteranceId)
    {
        Android.Util.Log.Debug("TTS", $"@{DateTime.Now.Ticks}: Utterance {utteranceId} finished");
        _TTS.RaiseUtteranceFinished(utteranceId);
    }

    public override void OnError(string utteranceId)
    {
        Android.Util.Log.Warn("TTS", $"@{DateTime.Now.Ticks}: Utterance {utteranceId} errored");
        // Treat as finished to avoid the situation where a missing voice can lock the entire system. (Believed to have occurred on one test tablet).
        _TTS.RaiseUtteranceFinished(utteranceId);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Are you reusing the same TTS object, or recreating it each time? Is your activity/service/process in the foreground when this issue occurs?

Comment: @brandall, I'm reusing the same object. The activity is continually in the foreground.

Comment: I have quite a lot of experience with keeping the TTS object alive https://github.com/brandall76/Saiy-PS/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ai/saiy/android/service/SelfAware.java#L1199 and handling failures. But it being 'killed' mid use is very odd. Have you run the memory profiler to make sure your app doesn't have a leak? You may need to repeatedly run this until you can replicate the issue and then hopefully view the underlying cause. Also, check the context you are using is not tied to the Activity and instead to the application lifecycle. That's all I can think of for now.

Comment: It turned out that there was a leak of "native" memory which I wasn't seeing because I was just looking at the managed heap. Having fixed that, it may turn out that this is not reproducible - although I'm not sure that it's overly paranoid to still want an answer, because deadlocking is never good. FWIW I am definitely using the application's context.

Comment: Could you devise a unit test to replicate different usage patterns?